# What are some of the available options for music production software for Ubuntu?

Tags: music

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I am currently looking for a application that I can use to produce Rap/Hip-Hop music. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for free software, I hear that Luppp is pretty good. Bitwig Studio is a newly released non-free Digital Audio Workstation.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to check out [Ardour](http://ardour.org/). It's similar to Cubase for Windows.

You might also want to take a look at [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/). It comes with a bunch of media creator / editor software pre-installed.